# Non-blocking reading in background Qt thread on Linux caused EAGAIN

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt

Here is the minimal example of background data reading in Qt (available in [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/47622097/qt)). The program open file and read data byte-by-byte. The flow is the following:

```
//                            Flow
//
//          Widget                              Worker
//            +
//            | create thread
//            | create worker                     +
//            | move worker to thread             |
//            | start thread                      |
//            |                                   |
//            | start                     onStart |
//            |---------------------------------->|
//            |                                   |
//            | onReady                     ready |
//            |<----------------------------------|  .--<--.
//            |                 semaphore acquire |  |     |
//            | print data                        |  |     ^
//            |                                   |  v     |
//            | semaphore release                 |  |     |
//            |---------------------------------->|  `-->--
//            |                                   |
//            |                                   |
//            |                          finished |
//            |                                   |
//            | delete worker                     -
//            | detete thread
//            | quit application
//            -
```

The following code sometimes (about 1:30) caused `EAGAIN` error code when reading data from regular file.

```
$ ./rdqt ../main.cpp
Success 32768
$ ./rdqt ../main.cpp
Resource temporarily unavailable 32768
```

How is it possible for regular file? Or is this result of incorrect multithreading implementation?

```
.
├── main.cpp
├── Widget.cpp
├── Widget.h
├── Worker.cpp
└── Worker.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Widget.h"

int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    QApplication application (argc, argv);

    if (argc > 1) {
        Widget widget (argv [1]);
        widget.show ();

        return application.exec ();
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Widget.h**

```
#ifndef READ_DATA_WIDGET_H
#define READ_DATA_WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QThread>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include "Worker.h"                            

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Widget                 (const char *, QWidget * parent = nullptr);
        virtual ~Widget                 ();

    signals:
        void start                      ();

    public slots:
        void onReady                    (char);

    private:
        QThread                       * thread;
        QSemaphore                    * semaphore;
        Worker                        * worker;
};

#endif//READ_DATA_WIDGET_H
```

**Widget.cpp**

```
#include "Widget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>

Widget::Widget (const char * path, QWidget * parent)
        : QWidget       (parent)
        , thread        {new QThread}
        , semaphore     {new QSemaphore (1)}
        , worker        {new Worker (path, semaphore)}
{
    connect (this, & Widget::start, worker, & Worker::onStart);
    connect (worker, & Worker::ready, this, & Widget::onReady);
    connect (worker, & Worker::finish, [this]() {
        thread->quit ();
        /*QApplication::quit ();*/
    });

    worker->moveToThread (thread);
    thread->start ();

    emit start          ();
}

Widget::~Widget ()
{
    worker->deleteLater ();
    thread->deleteLater ();
}

void Widget::onReady (char /*c*/)
{
    /*qDebug ("%c", c);*/
    semaphore->release ();
}
```

**Worker.h**

```
#ifndef READ_DATA_WORKER_H
#define READ_DATA_WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSemaphore>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Worker                 (const char *, QSemaphore *);
        virtual ~Worker                 () = default;

    signals:
        void ready                      (char);
        void finish                     ();

    public slots:
        void onStart                    ();

    private:
        const char *                    path;
        QSemaphore                    * semaphore;
};

#endif//READ_DATA_WORKER_H
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
#include "Worker.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

Worker::Worker (const char * path, QSemaphore * semaphore)
        : QObject   ()
        , path      {path}
        , semaphore {semaphore}
{
}

void Worker::onStart ()
{
    int file = open (path, O_RDONLY);
    char b;

    while (read (file, & b, 1) > 0) {
        semaphore->acquire ();
        emit ready (b);
    }
    qDebug () << strerror (errno) << (fcntl (file, F_GETFL) /*& O_NONBLOCK*/);

    emit finish ();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a mutex at all? The worker object seems to be the only place the file is accessed. Also, you're locking the mutex multiple times inside the while-loop, which will result in a deadlock if the mutex is not constructed as recursive (as this one is).

Comment: @bnaecker, in the real code passed a lot of data which need to be processed before next loop will be performed. So waiting on mutex.lock in worker thread is by design. Also without mutex the problem isn't reproduced ;) . Can you explain how a deadlock can happen for non-recursive mutex?

Comment: Although probably not related to the issue, but I would `QThread::wait()` on `thread` somewhere between `QApplication::quit()` and `delete thread`. As it's theoretically possible for QApplication thread to finish earlier (after Worker::finish but still while Worker being in the QEventLoop).

Comment: @absolute.madness That's what `QObject::deleteLater()` is for.

Comment: @Gluttton If the mutex is non-recursive, calling `lock()` twice from the same thread is just like calling `lock()` from another thread. It blocks until the mutex becomes available, which obviously will never happen. Even in a recursive mutex, you must call `unlock()` once for each call to `lock()`, so they can be difficult to get right. Your design sounds better suited to a semaphore or condition variable rather than a mutex anyway: waiting in one place until something happens, allowing that section to proceed.

Comment: @Gluttton I somewhat agree with @bnaecker about the design. Calling `QMutex::unlock` from another thread leads to problems, see the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#unlock). I mean `connect (this, & Widget::request, worker, & Worker::onRequest, Qt::DirectConnection)`. I think sticking to QMutexLocker is a good idea from this viewpoint.

Comment: @bnaecker, `Your design sounds better suited to a semaphore or condition variable rather than a mutex anyway` thanks, you are totally right! I rewrite my example and migrate from `QMutex` on `QSemaphore` but the problem is still exists (but significantly rare about 1:30).

Comment: I don't even understand how `EAGAIN` can be returned. You're not opening the file with `O_NONBLOCK` flag, right? Or setting it to non-blocking with `fcntl`?

Comment: @bnaecker, `You're not opening the file with O_NONBLOCK flag, right? Or setting it to non-blocking with fcntl?`, right. I accept that sometimes I can get `EAGAIN` (which means that I was interrupted by a OS signal during blocking read). But in my case if I get `EAGAIN` ones I will get it continuously in loop again.

Comment: Can anybody reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Gluttton If a signal interrupted the call, `errno` should be set to `EINTR`, not `EAGAIN`. I still don't understand how it's possible you're getting `EAGAIN` with a non-blocking, regular file.

Comment: @Gluttton Yes, I confirm, the problem is reproducible. But I'm not sure it comes from file reading, read doesn't change errno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main answer

Ok, I finally got it. The errno is set internally when locking a mutex by Qt either when calling `semaphore->acquire ();` or when emitting a signal with `emit ready (b);` (Qt uses synchronisation objects for queued connections, obviously). Here's how to debug where errno change happens. I added the following line at the beginning of `Worker::onStart`:

```
qDebug() << QString("0x%1").arg(reinterpret_cast<quint64>(&errno), 0, 16);
```

and set a breakpoint on the next line in debugger. Having this address (e.g. 0x7fffda6ce668) I added a memory breakpoint in gdb with `watch *0x7fffda6ce668` in the gdb console (if you use Qt Creator, enable Window -> Views -> Debugger Log). I immediately got the backtrace for the errno change:

```
#0  0x00007ffff63964ae in syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:42
#1  0x00007ffff6eb0610 in QBasicMutex::lockInternal() () from /home/(my-user-name)/apps/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff70a7199 in QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject*, QEvent*, int) () from /home/(my-user-name)/apps/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff70d3286 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/(my-user-name)/apps/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x000000000040494f in Worker::ready (this=0x8d1550, _t1=0 '\\000') at moc_Worker.cpp:142
#5  0x0000000000403dee in Worker::onStart (this=0x8d1550) at ../qt/Worker.cpp:63
```

Now, QMutex is implemented in corelib/thread/qmutex_linux.cpp and uses a [futex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) which causes errno == 11 sometimes. I've no idea why this happens, sorry, might be someone's bug ;) You can check the qmutex_linux.cpp code and try to find relevant info on the net for yourself. If you are interested if a specific API call produces an error you can set `errno=0` before this call and check it after the call. Btw, I tested it without any file io just sending a dummy character with ready(0), the result was the same. So the problem is not file io.

### Previous answer (mostly irrelevant after your code changes)

I think what you're trying to achieve with a QMutex alone is classically done with QMutex and QWaitCondition:

```
void Worker::onStart ()
{
    // ...
    while (true) {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        if(read (file, & b, 1) <= 0)
            break;
        emit ready (b);
        // waitCondition unlocks the mutex and 
        // waits till waitCondition wakeAll/wakeOne is called
        // signalling that Widget has finished processing
        waitCondition.wait(&mutex);
    }
    // ...
}

void Worker::onRequest ()
{
    // re-locks the mutex and continues the while cycle
    waitCondition.wakeAll();
}
```

Here `waitCondition` is a member variable like `mutex`. I haven't checked this code. It's just for illustration of the idea, you may need to change it a little. Links for reference: QWaitCondition [description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) and [usage example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your solution shortly.

Comment: I've tried proposed solution, but unfortunately it does not eliminate the main problem and I still sometimes get `EAGAIN`.

Comment: @Gluttton It was just my guess, since you said that without QMutex the problem is not reproducible and Qt docs say that unlocking QMutex from another thread is an error. Btw, QSemaphore internally is implemented as QMutex + QWaitCondition, so using QSemaphore is similar to my suggestion in this answer.

Comment: @Gluttton No problem :) memory breakpoints sometimes do wonders. Btw, since very little code of yours is involved I'm inclined to think it's a QTBUG. Quick googling didn't reveal anything relevant in their tracker. If you file it pls post a link here.

Comment: By the way, the easiest workaround for such cases is set `errno = 0` before each call of function which result are checked.